# Copy range of cells from one sheet to another

Tags: vba, excel

I want to copy a column with a varying number of entries (by using .End(xlDown)) into column C of another sheet going downwards.

```
With Sheets("General Text")
    Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Copy 
    Destination:=Sheets("Compiler").Range(Range("C2"), Range("C2").End(xlDown))
End With
```

I'm not sure if this is the easiest method, but I've tried a few iterations and it always errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, using `Copy` with `Destination` is a 1-line command (not 2).

Second, you need to fully qualify your `Range` inside the `With Sheets("General Text")` statement, by addind a `.` as a prefix.

Try the code below:

```
With Sheets("General Text")
    .Range(.Range("A2"), .Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Compiler").Range("C2")
End With
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer - it now works as intended. Is there an easier way to define the range? Rather than using ".Range(.Range("A2"), .Range....etc"

Comment: @MolarBear depends on what kind of `Range` you are trying to define. If you want to define continous range (without blanks in the middle) then this way is quite Accustomed